# Is it possible to identify parts of a known image

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Imagine you have a big place like a shopping mall and I have a 360 degree picture of several places inside and outside of it. Is it possible through Cognitive Services/Computer Vision to compare if a photo taken by users of my app is related to any of these 360 degree pictures so I can add a description saying what is in the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Cognitive Services - Computer Vision currently does not offer this type of functionality. Training or customization is not yet supported.  This is a highly requested feature and under review.